# Multiple Sidekiq Processes on a single dyno

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

My Rails app on Heroku has a `Procfile` that starts up a single Sidekiq process on my dyno

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Is it possible to start up multiple sidekiq processes on the same dyno?

My organization has a large dyno with a lot of memory that we're not using. Before downgrading the dyno, I was wondering if it was an option instead to make use of it by running multiple Sidekiq processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sidekiq Enterprise's Multi-Process](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Multi-Process) feature makes this trivial.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to run Sidekiq with a supervisor like https://github.com/ochinchina/supervisord

Add the binary to your repository (e.g. bin/supervisord) and add a config file and a Procfile entry.

For a dyno with 8 cores, your configuration could look like this:

```
[program:sidekiq]
command = bundle exec sidekiq -e ${RACK_ENV:-development} -C config/sidekiq_large.yml
process_name = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
numprocs = 8
numprocs_start = 1
exitcodes = 0
stopsignal = TERM
stopwaitsecs = 40
autorestart = unexpected
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
```

Then in your Procfile:

```
worker_large: env [...] bin/supervisord -c sidekiq_worker_large.conf
```

Make sure that you tune your Sidekiq concurrency settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this open source third party gem that is meant to do this, without having to pay for Sidekiq Enterprise. I have not used it, don't know how well it works, but it looks good.

https://github.com/vinted/sidekiq-pool

It doesn't have any recent commits or many github stars, but may just be working fine?

Here's another one, that warns you it's unfinished work in progress, but just to compare:

https://github.com/kigster/sidekiq-cluster